# Hide a typo letter in an image in a pdf file

Tags: pdf, images

I have a typo legend in an image in my pdf file. There is an extra "t" at the end of the legend. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the correct image.
How can I remove that "t" in my pdf?

[image]

Comment: Use the Type tool and delete it. -- am I missing something?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this... what tools do you have?

Comment: @Scott it's an image embedded in a pdf. They can just extract the image, fix it in PS or Gimp and load it back in.

Comment: Is it an image @WELZ ? Kind of hard to tell here. And removing that 't" still won't correct the spelling for "estimated".

Comment: @Scott `I have a typo legend in an image in my pdf file` he can mix around the letters or correct them in any image editor.